# do.call with options in r to arrange ggplot list

Tags: r, ggplot2, do.call

I have my dummy data as:

```
x=1:7
y=1:7
df = data.frame(x=x,y=y)
bp <- vector("list", length = 4)
for (i in 1:4) {
 bp[[i]] <- ggplot(df,aes(x,y))+geom_point()
}
```

I have my ggplot objects in a list called `bp` with which I can generate a four-plot-grid as:

```
figure <- ggarrange(bp[[1]], bp[[2]], bp[[3]], bp[[4]],
                    labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                    ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
```

Now, I don't want to type `bp[[1]]..bp[[4]]` and want to use something like

`do.call(ggarrange, bp)` as you would do with function `grid.arrange` like `do.call(grid.arrange, bp)`. `do.call(grid.arrange, bp)` doesn't show the panel labels so I would like to use `ggarrange` and still would want to pass these arguments:

```
labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                    ncol = 2, nrow = 2
```

How can I use `do.call` in this case? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `ggarrange` (or really, `cowplot::plot_grid`) has a `plotlist` argument for this purpose. `ggarrange(plotlist = bp, labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), ncol = 2, nrow = 2)`. There is no need for `do.call`.

Comment: @akrun Yes it was for `do.call`. I did not explore any other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is to place it in a named `list` and concatenate the `list` elements

```
library(ggpubr)
do.call(ggarrange, c(bp, list(labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 ncol = 2, nrow = 2) ))
```

Here, the. OP's request is about using `do.call` with `ggarrange`.  Of course, it can be done without `do.call`

[image]

Comment: @MAPK You may need to have the corresponding size parameter also in the list

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out.