# using parse(text= )

Tags: r, parsing, expression

I thought I understood eval(parse(text =  )) but I am getting an error. I have a string named plotString that has been constructed using a for loop. If I print it out, it looks like this:

```
plotString
[1] "emo_plot[[1]],sentiment_plot[[1]],emo_plot[[2]],sentiment_plot[[2]],emo_plot[[3]],sentiment_plot[[3]],emo_plot[[4]],sentiment_plot[[4]],emo_plot[[5]],sentiment_plot[[5]],emo_plot[[6]],sentiment_plot[[6]],emo_plot[[7]],sentiment_plot[[7]],emo_plot[[8]],sentiment_plot[[8]],emo_plot[[9]],sentiment_plot[[9]],emo_plot[[10]],sentiment_plot[[10]]"
```

The end goal is to put it as the first argument in

```
pairPlot <- ggarrange( eval(parse(text=plotString)) + rremove("x.text"), labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), ncol = 6, nrow = 4)
```

But simply running it in

```
parse(text=plotString)
```

gives this error

```
Error in parse(text = plotString) : <text>:1:14: unexpected ','
1: emo_plot[[1]],
                 ^
```

and this

```
eval(parse(text=plotString))
```

gives, of course, the same

```
Error in parse(text = plotString) : <text>:1:14: unexpected ','
1: emo_plot[[1]],
                 ^
```

and this

```
pairPlot <- ggarrange( eval(parse(text=plotString)) + rremove("x.text"), labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), ncol = 6, nrow = 4)
```

gives, of course, the same

```
Error in parse(text = plotString) : <text>:1:14: unexpected ','
1: emo_plot[[1]],
                 ^
```

I have read that the text needs to evaluate to an R expression and I guess plotString is not an R expression. If that is the issue, how can I get the entry before the plus(+) sign in ggarrange() to be something like

```
emo_plot[[1]],sentiment_plot[[1]],emo_plot[[2]],sentiment_plot[[2]]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse()` parses *full expressions*. That is, the code that you pass it must be syntactically valid self-contained R code. You can’t pass it fragments. Even if you could do that, you can’t `eval()` fragments either; once again, the expression you pass to `eval()` must be self-contained, complete, valid R code.

I’d generally be wary of any use of `eval(parse(…))` in code; it’s usually solving the wrong problem.

In your case, where are you getting the input from? Unless the data comes from outside R, it’s almost certainly a better solution to store and manipulate the data as a list of expressions, not as a string. Then you can use it via `do.call()`:

```
do.call('ggarrange', list_of_plots)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for do.call. How are the arguments for ggarrange entered? Here is the call to ggarrange: ggarrange( emo_plot + rremove("x.text"), labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),ncol = 2, nrow = 6)

Comment: do.call('ggarrange', emo_plot) works but I don't see how to set the column and row numbers.

Comment: I see an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57810140/do-call-with-options-in-r-to-arrange-ggplot-list